# How to solve " org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, dependency-injection

I have this structure in spring project :

```
class A {
   public void first(){
   }
}

class B extends A {
   public void first(){
   }
}
```

I want to call method first of Class A or Class B depending upon a condition, but I am getting this exception "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.code.A' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: B,A
" in spring.

I tried adding @Qualifier and other things but nothing worked, can anyone suggest any change?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Annotation to get bean into spring context, you can try to rename these bean in different name ,such as @Component(value="classA"), so that spring will identify these two class which is subclass in a common class;

In general, we often define a interface which is abstract and used for subclassed by other purpose instead of class .
If you refactor you code  like above , you will reduce  the risk which occur the error  like that the bean in spring context is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case and code sample are not explaining enough on what you try to achieve. Could you elaborate ?

Your `first` methods can't be beans since they return void. If you want to store instances, then :

```java
@Component
class A {
   public void first(){
   }
}

@Component
class B extends A {
   public void first(){
   }
}
```

This code will tell Spring to create & store singleton instances of each A & B (under the names A & B) into the Spring context. Spring can then inject these instances where needed:

```java
@Component
class C {

    private final A instanceA;
    private final B instanceB;

    @Inject
    private void setInstanceA( A a ) {
        this.instanceA = a;
    }
    @Inject
    private void setInstanceB( B b ) {
        this.instanceB = b;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        //call a.first() or b.first();
    }
}
```

If you elaborate more on what you want to achieve, it will easier to give a better answer.

Comment: Actually, I have a class A which is old and contains many methods. So, now I want to add a new class B and inherit some of the methods of class A(not all). By doing this, spring was throwing unique bean exception.  I was also thinking of creating an interface and use in both classes A and B but still I have to extend A in B as I don't want to write all those implementations again.  @peng

Comment: @rana you need to post more information with sample code : current code (with annotations) and what you'd like to get. Right now, you are hard to understand : there's no sample of bean definition in your post and you ask question to solve a unique bean exception ... Please give the full path to understand how it happens.

Comment: It got resolved actually without using Qualifier or anything else. Thank you for responding so fast, I appreciate that. I know the information was not adequate, I will keep this in mind in future.